How to save something to local storage by async functions when the component is going to be unmounted
I'm trying to create a auto-save config page. I hope it could load the config file (just a json file now) to state, and then you can edit it through ui components. And when you switch to another page, the state could save back to the config file. I'm not sure how to achieve it.
Currently I use useEffect with a [] as the second parameter to do it. Accurding to the official doc, it will run the setup function which passed as the first parameter when the component is mounted, and run the returned cleaner function when it's unmounted. But, may since the load/save operations are async functions, it runs quite different from my expectations.
here are my code, include some debug log:
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState<settingStruct>({});

  const loadSettings = async () => {
    const savedSetting = await loadJsonFile<settingStruct>("settings.json", {});
    console.log("load: ", settings);
    setSettings(savedSetting!);
  };

  const saveSettings = async () => {
    console.log("save: ", settings);
    await saveJsonFile('settings.json', settings);
  };

  useEffect(() => {  // here I hope it could achieve auto-load/save
    loadSettings();
    return () => {
      saveSettings();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("changed: ", settings)
  }, [settings]);

In addition, I temporarily added a button that can be triggered manually to run saveSettings().
Then, after a test, I got console log as followed:
// switch to the page

changed:  {}                       // init value

save:  {}                          // react's strict mode, run an additional setup and cleaner, however the order is wrong

changed:  {}                       // not sure why it's triggered

load:  {}                          // two setup and changes caused by them

changed:  {}

load:  {}

changed:  {}

changed:  {authKey: '1234567'}    // here I pasted something to input component, and it triggered state update operation

save:  {authKey: '1234567'}       // manual save, it looks good

save:  {}                         // cleaner triggered because I switched to another page, but it saved an empty object(specifically the init value), not the latest state

There are two problem, the first is the wrong order of strict mode's setup -> cleaner -> setup calls, I believe it's because they are async functions, so react don't know the previous didn't finished. It caused the init value to be saved before updated by loaded value, and I don't konw how to fix it. However, it seemed not a problem in production environment.
The second problem, which I can't understand at all, is that the cleaner triggered when the component is unmounted, always just save the init value, no matter what the state actually is. This caused my function to be completely unavailable at all
I wonder how to fix these, or how to achieve this auto-save function correctly.

if you define and call the saveSettings function directly inside the effect cleaner, does this solve the 2nd problem you are having?

@quentinkrammer nothing changed. Even log settingState in cleaner but not saveSettings can only got init value. It's really weird to me. I wonder if it's because the state is lost when cleaner is called?

lets say you have an effect with a dependency array which contains a state variable foo.
now someone calls setFoo to change the state.
at this point the effects cleanup function is called once with the OLD value of foo.
after this the component would render and the effect would be called with the new value of 'foo'.
in your case the dependency array is empty.
hence when the cleaner function runs and is using the old state, this state matches the initial state.
at least I am 90% sure.
what you need is an effect that has settings in its dependency array and calls saveSettings

@quentinkrammer It does make sense. I have made some tests. It seems that only put settings into the array can the latest value be guaranteed. But it's not what I want. I don't want to keep saving it everytime I changed a little bit, but only save once before I leave this page. I just found useEffectEvent, it seems to be what I need. But I don't want to believe that there is no other way to implement this function without this experimental hook for so long

are you sure this is what you want? a user might close the application without the component ever unmounting. e.g by closing the browser.

@quentinkrammer Sorry to make you feel puzzled, this design is't such stable, but, yes, this is what I want.  I'm new to react and just writing a small toy just for myself, so more accurate, this "config save logic" isn't important at all, I am more troubled by this feature of useEffect. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Please try to introduce settingsRef which gets updated when settings changes. settingsRef.current is used in saveSettings.
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState<settingStruct>({});
  const settingsRef = useRef(settings);

  const saveSettings = async () => {
    await saveJsonFile('settings.json', settingsRef.current);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadSettings();
    return () => {
      saveSettings();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("changed: ", settings)
    settingsRef.current = settings; // update settingsRef
  }, [settings]);

The explanation for doing this, is that the useEffect with empty dependency array is invoked just once, hence saveSettings is rendered with the initial state only.

This is indeed effective. Thank you so much!
